# Writing Letter by mouse using flash

Tags: flash

how to create letter ( A, B , C.. ) using flash such that it appears outlined only and the kid moves the mouse inside it to fill with color .. using flash or any other technology..
thanks

Comment: I could imagine you can easily get such an effect when using two fonts, one outline font and a normal font of the same font family. You show the letters in the outline font and when you want to color them you put the same letter in a normal font on top, maybe adding some transparency. This could be done in plain html/javascript, no flash required. But I am pretty sure you have to code that yourself, I don't think something like this exists as a ready-to-use solution.

Comment: ok, but i want the kid to draw the letter by moving the mouse over the outlined path

Comment: Ah, ok. Tricky. You need a path that describes how each letter is written, a function. Then you poll the mouse position on a periodical base and compare that position to the function. If the position stays withing a certain precision of the function value then the letter is written "cleanly". If the distance gets too big then this attempt has failed. Maybe SVG helps here, it has a very good and clear support of letters (characters) and paths.